# Testing differences between slopes by examining proportions rather than interactions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, interaction, proportion

In a [recent article published in Nature Genetics](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v47/n7/full/ng.3292.html), Francioli et al. argue that the relationship between paternal age and mutation rate depends on what part of the genome you're looking at  (intergenic versus genic regions; see image below). If I were to test this question, I would fit a model similar to the following:

$$N_{mutations} = \beta_0 + \beta_1Age + \beta_2Region + \beta_3Age\times Region$$

where $Region$ would be a contrast- or -dummy coded predictor testing whether the relationship between mutations and age did in fact depend on whether you were examining intergenic versus genic regions of the genome. E.g., observed mutations in a genic region might receive a score of $+\frac{1}{2}$ for $Region$ whereas those in intergenic regions would receive a score of $-\frac{1}{2}$.

The authors, however appear to have instead examined the following model:

$$\frac{N_{genic}}{N_{genic}+N_{intergenic}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Age$$

and interpreted the significant slope for age to indicate that, looking at the figure below, "the steeper slope of the regression line for genic mutations indicates a faster relative increase in the rate of genic mutations in comparison to intergenic mutations with paternal age."

I understand that this is asking a different question than the one I posed above (i.e. examining the change in the *proportion* of genic versus intergenic mutations over time as presented with the green line in the figure) but I'm unsure of the circumstances under which these methods would yield divergent results.

[image: Figure]

In case it is difficult to read, the top panel shows "percent genic mutation" as a function of paternal age along and displays a p-value of .0085. The bottom panel shows the log transformed mutation count as a function of paternal age split into genic versus intergenic categories. The red line is the predicted log mutation count in genic regions and the teal/blue line is the predicted log mutation count in intergenic regions.

**The question boils down comparing the following models**:

#### Model 1

$$Count_{total} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 (G_1 vs. G_2) + \beta_3 [X\times  (G_1 vs. G_2)]$$

#### Model 2

$$\frac{Count_{G_1}}{Count_{total}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$$

where $X$ is a continuous predictor and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are mutually exclusive groups that split up the observations. We're concerned in the difference between what $\beta_3$ in model 1 tests and what $\beta_1$ in model 2 tests.

**What are the differences between the questions these models are asking? Are they relying on different sets of assumptions? What would divergent results between these two methods indicate?**

---

### EDIT

As pointed out in the comments, it appears that they were examining log-transformed mutation counts with the red/blue lines in the figure. So I would add to the question a third model and again ask under what circumstances the results here would differ from those of models 1 and 2:

#### Model 3

$$ \mbox{log } Count_{total} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 (G_1 vs. G_2) + \beta_3 [X\times  (G_1 vs. G_2)]$$

Comment: It took me some time to realize that the lower subplot on the figure is on logarithmic scale, i.e. the red/blue line fits do not correspond to your Model 1.

Comment: You're correct about the scale of the plot. However, the authors describe the analyses that generated those results as linear regression: "The red line shows the least-squares regression for genic mutations (P < 2 × 10−16); the blue line shows the least-squares regression for intergenic mutations (P = 3.7 × 10−14)... We used linear regression models to compute the increase in the number of mutations with paternal age for genic (β = 0.52; P < 2 × 10−16) and intergenic (β = 0.32; P = 3.7 × 10−14) mutations separately while correcting for coverage." I'm not sure why the lines are straight...

Comment: I think they are fitting logs with linear regression.

Comment: Could you provide a larger version of the figure, or would that violate copyright? I can access it through institutional affiliation, but I'm worried that some readers might not be able to.

Comment: @ChrisC I'm worried about that too but I didn't want to post anything not publicly available. Fortunately, it's a pretty simple graphic. I'll add a better description of it in the question.

Comment: Better safe than sorry, thanks for adding the description.

Comment: Is $Region$ an indicator for "genic versus nongenic"?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes! Will edit to make more clear.

Comment: What is the unit of analysis in these models (i.e., what does a row of the dataset represent)? Am I correct in assuming that the unit of analysis is different for models 1 and 2? It looks like in model 2 each row is a person, while in model 1 each row is an individual region, and the DV is constant for rows/regions from the same person. Can you clarify? Clearly defined subscripts in the model definitions would help.